# General Leibniz's rule, why cases k=0 and k=n are separated from the sum?

Tags: derivatives, binomial-coefficients

[image]

1) Firstly, I don't understand why cases $n=0$ and $k=n$ are seperated from the sum?

2) Then if we put k=1 then why n on the top of the sum symbol still stays the same instead of changing to $n+1$?

3) Why after the first summation f is derived in k-th order instead of $(k+1)$ like before? And if the n on the sum symbol doesn't change, then why do function $g$ is derived at $(n+1-k)$ th order? ( You can correct my terminology.)

4) Why after the second summation symbol there is $k-1$?

Answer (score 1):

The  following    might     be   helpful.

> **Ad (1)**
>
> Firstly, I don't understand why cases $n=0$ and $k=n$ are separated from the sum?

In fact it is not plausible  to separate  the cases $n=0$ and $k=n$  at this moment. It  becomes  more  plausible  when  we change the  order  of the steps.

Note, splitting the summation was  done in order to use the binomial identity

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We start with the line commented with "splitting the summation" and obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\left(f(x)g(x)\right)^{(n+1)}}\\
> &\quad=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{(k+1)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x)
> +\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n+1-k)}(x)\\
> &\quad=\sum_{k=\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{n+1}}\binom{n}{\color{blue}{k-1}}f^{(\color{blue}{k})}(x)g^{(n\color{blue}{+1-k})}(x)
> +\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n+1-k)}(x)\tag{3}\\
> &\quad=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k-1}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n+1-k)}(x)+\binom{n}{n}f^{(n+1)}(x)g(x)\right)\\
> &\quad\qquad+\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n+1-k)}(x)+\binom{n}{0}f(x)g^{(n+1)}(x)\right)\tag{4}\\
> &\quad=\binom{n}{0}f(x)g^{(n+1)}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n+1-k)}(x)\\
> &\quad\qquad+\binom{n}{n}f^{(n+1)}(x)g(x)\tag{5}\\
> &\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n+1-k)}(x)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we  shift the  index  of the  left-hand sum by one to start with $k=1$. We now  have the convenient situation that  we   can use the  binomial  identity from (2).  But the  sums   do not have  the same   index  region.

  *This* is   the reason why  we  separate  the  case $k=n+1$  from the  left-hand sum  and the  case   $k=0$   from  the right-hand  sum in (4).
- In  (5)  we can apply  (2) since we have separated the two cases where the indices do not coincide.
- In (6) we merge the single terms back into the sum.

> The above derivation should help to also clarify parts of the other questions.  A  somewhat more detailed look to the index-shift in (3):
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n f(k)&=f(0)+f(1)+\cdots+f(n)\\
> \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}f(k-1)&=f(0)+f(1)+\cdots+f(n)\\
> \sum_{k=-1}^{n-1}f(k+1)&=f(0)+f(1)+\cdots+f(n)
> \end{align*}
>
> Note  that an index shift  by one implies an argument shift by one in the other direction.